# webtechnick Facebook logout not working

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I am using webtechnick facebook plugin, i have everything set and its FB login works perfectly.

I am using  `$fbc =$this->Connect->User();`  to fetch FB details of logged in user

And using

```
<?php 
    echo $facebook->login(array('perms' => 'email,publish_stream','size'=>'small')); 
?>

<?php
    echo $this->Facebook->logout(); 
?>
```

for login,logout respectively. i am getting details of user after login, but it will not unset after performing a logout();

I am using webtechnick fb plugin version 3.1.1 .  Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My help isn't much help because I haven't really found a solution.  The good news is that you are not alone:

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/issues/43

What I can tell you is that the facebook cookie (fbsr_{facebook_app_id}) is either not deleting or is being recreated and that is the root of the problem.

***EDIT***

I may have found out what's going on here.  Until the other night I had not bothered to setup my .htaccess files and both http:/www.example.com and http:/example.com were valid.

In my facebook app, I had set up example.com as a domain and pointed the site URL to www.example.com.

With the fbsr_{app id} cookie, I noticed that it was sometimes on the http://example.com while my cakephp cookies were on www.

I played around with changing the URL in my facebook app (adding www, removing www) and then also started doing the rewrite rules in .htaccess to add or remove www.  I just removed the appdomain entirely from my facebook app, forced www. to the domain, and now everything is kosher.

So I think the trick is to

1. Not have the app domain in the facebook app
2. Fix canonicalization of www via .htaccess

This ensures that both the cakephp and the facebook cookies are being saved to the identical domain, and when you logout they are removed from said domain.

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late for some suggestion for this post. Still feel it might help some one who later reading this post.

I too was facing the logout issue with the plugin , I have modified a function in ConnectComponent in the plugin to clear its session details if the action is "logout". Below is the modified function :

```
private function __syncFacebookUser(){

        if($this->Controller->params['action'] == 'logout')
            {
                $this->Controller->Session->delete('FB');
                $this->uid = null;
                $this->Controller->Session->delete('Auth.User');
            }
            else
            {
            if(!isset($this->Controller->Auth)){
            return false;
        }

        $Auth = $this->Controller->Auth;
        if (!$this->__initUserModel()) {
            return false;
        }
        // if you don't have a facebook_id field in your user table, throw an error
        if(!$this->User->hasField('facebook_id')){
            $this->__error("Facebook.Connect handleFacebookUser Error.  facebook_id not found in {$Auth->userModel} table.");
            return false;
        }

        // check if the user already has an account
        // User is logged in but doesn't have a 
        if($Auth->user('id')){
            $this->hasAccount = true;
            $this->User->id = $Auth->user($this->User->primaryKey);
            if (!$this->User->field('facebook_id')) {
                $this->User->saveField('facebook_id', $this->uid);
            }
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            // attempt to find the user by their facebook id
            $this->authUser = $this->User->findByFacebookId($this->uid);
            //if we have a user, set hasAccount
            if(!empty($this->authUser)){
                $this->hasAccount = true;
            }
            //create the user if we don't have one
            elseif(empty($this->authUser) && $this->createUser) {
                $this->authUser[$this->User->alias]['facebook_id'] = $this->uid;
                $this->authUser[$this->User->alias][$this->modelFields['password']] = $Auth->password(FacebookInfo::randPass());
                if($this->__runCallback('beforeFacebookSave')){
                    $this->hasAccount = ($this->User->save($this->authUser, array('validate' => false)));
                }
                else {
                    $this->authUser = null;
                }
            }
            //Login user if we have one
            if($this->authUser){
                $this->__runCallback('beforeFacebookLogin', $this->authUser);
                $Auth->authenticate = array(
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array('username' => 'facebook_id', 'password' => $this->modelFields['password'])
                    )
                );
                if($Auth->login($this->authUser[$this->model])){
                    $this->__runCallback('afterFacebookLogin');
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

For me now the facebook plugin is working fine for facebook connect.